# Loopback MongoDB Connector: map properties to field names?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback's [MongoDB connector](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/MongoDB+connector) to expose a RESTful API to query and update a MongoDB collection.

When I defined the model it didn't let me define property names with spaces in them, so instead of *"Gas 93"* I had to use *"gas93"*. The example is trivial but affect 9 properties of my collection.

I know you can map properties to table fields with the [PostgreSQL connector](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/PostgreSQL+connector)

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "required": false,
        "postgresql": {
          "columnName": "username",
     }
 }
```

I haven't found a way to do the same for MongoDB fieldnames. I have a lot of features in my app using collection fieldNames as they are now, so I'd like to avoid changing them to adapt to loopback.

Is there a way to do this? Documentation doesn't say it but, then again, it doesn't say you can't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoopBack doesn't support property mapping for mongoDB at the moment, only collection names can be customized.  We will update the documentation to clarify this.

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to add that, while you can't declare model properties with blank spaces in ```slc loopback:model``` the properties will be quoted in the json model definition afterwards, so at that point I could edit each property manually to match MongoDB field names.

Comment: Hi, would you please show how to customize collection names? I'm currently facing this challenge and your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a pull request to support this:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/189